# Compactness, Hausdorffness and a Descending Sequence of Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Still studying topology and recently stumbled on Exercise 41/Chapter 11  in Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis (4th edition). Thing is, I feel my proof is incorrect because it doesn't use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff. I'll enunciate propositions and definitions at the end of the proof.

**Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a compact, Hausdorff topological space and $\{F_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a descending collection of closed subsets of $X$. Let $O$ be a neighborhood of the intersection $\cap_{n = 1}^\infty F_n$. Show there is an index $N$ such that $F_n \subseteq O$ for $n \geq N$.**

We start with the fact that $O$ is a neighborhood of the intersection, that is, $\cap_{n = 1}^\infty F_n \subseteq O$, where $O \in \mathcal{T}$. This implies that:
\begin{equation}
(X - O) \subseteq (X -  \cap_{n = 1}^\infty F_n) = \cup_{n = 1}^\infty (X - F_n) \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $X - O$ is closed, as the complement of an open set, and $\{(X - F_n)\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ an open cover of $X - O$. By proposition 1, $X - O$ is compact. I'm assuming my mistake lies in the next step. Using **Claim 1** there exists a finite subcover $\{(X - F_{n_k})\}_{k = 1}^m \;$ of $X - O$, i.e.:

\begin{equation}
(X - O) \subseteq \cup_{k = 1}^m(X - F_{n_k}) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

let $t = max\{n_1, ..., n_m\}$. We argue that

\begin{equation}
\cup_{i  =  t + 1}^\infty \, F_{i} \cap (X - O) = \varnothing  \tag{3}
\end{equation}

By contradiction, assume there is $w \in \cup_{i  =  t + 1}^\infty \, F_{i} \cap (X - O) \neq \varnothing$. Since $w \in (X - O)$, Because of $(2)$, there is $ k\in \{1, ..., m\}$ s.t. $w \in (X - F_{n_k})$. Also, there is $i \in \mathbb{N} - \{1, ..., t\}$ s.t. $ w \in F_i$. Because the sequence is descending and $i > n_k$ it has to be the case that $F_i \subseteq F_{n_k}$, meaning $w \in F_{n_k}$, a contradiction. Hence $(3)$ holds.

Finally, by $(3)$, $\cup_{i  =  t + 1}^\infty \, F_{i} \subseteq O$. Now, if we define $N = t + 1$ then for arbitrary $n \geq N$, $F_n \subseteq \cup_{i  =  t + 1}^\infty \, F_{i} \subseteq O$, proving the exercise.

---

**Definition$_1$**: A topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is said to be **compact** provided every open conver of $X$ has a finite subcover. A subset $K$ of $X$ is called **compact** provided $K$, considere as a topological space $(K, \mathcal{S})$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the inherited topology from $X$, is compact.

**Definition$_2$**: For a subset $K$ of a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, we call a subset $A$ of $X$ a **neighborhood of $K$** if $A$ is open and $K \subseteq A$.

**Proposition 1**: A closed subset $K$ of a compact topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is compact. (Page 234 - Royden's Real Analysis)

**Claim 1**: If $K$ is a compact subset of the topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, then every convering of $K$ by a collection of open subsets of $X$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: **Claim 1** was something I assume I proved in another context, but now I'm really not sure if its true. If needed I can provide the proof of this claim, so it can also be analysed.

Comment: I see no need for the space to be Hausdorff. Maybe if $F_n$ were compact, not necessarily closed, you would need the space to be Hausdorff (just to conclude $F_n$ are closed). Your "claim 1" seems correct. It is even "iff".

Comment: If not, then all $F_n\setminus O$ are closed nested and non-empty. So their intersection is non-empty and a point in their intersection contradicts $\bigcap_n F_n \subseteq O$. QED

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What you're saying is that Hausdorffness guarantees that the intersection is contained in $O$, right?

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro No. Hausdorff is not needed here, just compactness if the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the case that $X$ need not be Hausdorf at all, and your proof shows this correctly; I'll recap it in shorter form:

If $\bigcap_n F_n \subseteq O$, where $O$ is open, then $\{X-F_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \} \cup \{O\}$ is an open cover of $X$ (if $p$ is in no $X-F_n$, it's in all $F_n$, so in $O$) and there is a finite subcover $\{X-F_{n_1}, X-F_{n_2},\ldots, X-F_{n_k}\} \cup \{O\}$ where $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots n_k$, say, and then $F_{n_k} \subseteq O$ by the nestedness (if $p \in F_{n_k}$, then $p \notin X-F_{n_i}$ for $i \le k$ and so must be in $O$).

Comment: Kindly appreciated!

Comment: @GiordanoRibeiro glad it helped you!